# Autocomplete filter using Sharepoint PerformancePoint Dashboard Designer

Tags: filter, performancepoint

I am using Sharepoint 2010 with PerformancePoint Dashboard Designer.

I am creating a dashboard that has a filter at the top of the page. The filter contains a very long list of items and I was wonder if there is a possibility to create an auto complete filter that could be substituted for the regular filter for the dashboard. This would allow users to begin typing their filter and the dropdown would autocomplete it.

As a secondary part to this question: Is it possibly to use a Web Part to be a filter for a dashboard in dashboard designer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, as you've discovered, it isn't possible out of the box.

You can upgrade to SharePoint 2013 and PerformancePoint Services 2013 which now includes filter search.  See [What's New in PerformancePoint Services 2013](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/performancepoint/archive/2012/08/03/what-s-new-in-performancepoint-services-2013.aspx).  Not exactly the same as auto-complete, but pretty dang close.

Or, you could look at creating your own filter using the SDK.  See [PerformancePoint Services Code Sample: Custom Report, Filter, and Tabular Data Source Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee558401%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

Regarding your second question, you can add a Web Part when you edit the dashboard in SharePoint, but not when you edit the dashboard in Dashboard Designer.  See [Maintain, edit, and update PerformancePoint dashboards](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh344829%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: I try to download the reference sample mentioned above from: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ppsSdkRefSample but it doesn't work and an error on the page is thrown. Thoughts?

Comment: Check the Application Event log.

Comment: Sorry - The download from the site isn't work. So I can't run any samples without the download

Comment: @htkhtk, I tested it and it works for me in Google Chrome.  Beyond that, I don't know, sorry.

Comment: Thanks! It was my firewall at work. They always seem to block stuff I did.